# Express the limit in terms of $f'(x_{0})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the following limit in terms of $f'(x_{0})$:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0} - 3h) - f(x_{0})} {h}
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a derivative? What have you tried?

Comment: Multiply by $3\cdot(1/3)$.

Comment: I know the limit definition of the derivative( both with $h \to 0$ and with $x \to x_{0}$ and I've tried adding and subtracting $f( x_{0} +h)$ to the numerator but got stuck with what was left afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the variable in the limit as follows (there is no need of L'Hospital' rule):

-3h=t and then you will obtain:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+t) - f(x_0)}{-t/3}= -3f'(x_0)$$

Comment: I think you should substitute with $-3h = t$ as the derivative is mostly defined as the limit of $\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$. Also, then the result is consistent with the application of L'Hospital's rule.